# Executing try/catch on different Window in IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Consider a page containing an iframe. The iframe's content might look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.foo = function () {
        nonExisting();
    };
    window.bar = function () {
        throw "An error!";
    };
</script>
```

Now, I wanna execute something like this:

```
try {
    iframe.contentWindow.foo();
} catch (e) { console.log('ok'); }
```

and

```
try {
    iframe.contentWindow.bar();
} catch (e) { console.log('ok'); }
```

This is what I get:

- Chrome/Firefox/Opera - 'ok', 'ok'
  (expected behaviour)
- IE8 - "Object expected" error, Uncaught Exception

WTF is going on here? How could that be an uncaught exception when I'm using a try/catch block? Is that a bug? Or does anything in the specs allow this behaviour?
And most importantly: Can I make it work as it should?

Comment: you mean why does stuff work in chrome/ff/opera and not in IE? well, let me tell you a little story..

Comment: What's going on here is something that web developers worldwide discovered years ago: IE doesn't play nice.

Comment: Right, it's just that I'm very surprised that nobody encountered this bug before. Usually I find dozens of websites describing a particular IE bug and offering workarounds. This time however I feel pretty helpless. As mentioned, the main question is: Can I make it work somehow?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have a typo: `"An error"!`.

If I run it without that typo on IE9 with IE8 emulated, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/vsSgE/3/.

Comment: See I hate this jumping on the bandwagon that IE is bad. If anything IE just catches more of people's mistakes and lets you know about it. If you code it correctly you won't have a problem. There are differences in each of the browsers, but if you catch your own problems you will be able to get your site up and working in all browsers.

Comment: BTW @pimvdb - That wasn't having a go at your solution, it was using your solution as an example of people blaming lazy coding on IE.

Comment: @anothershrubery In all seriousness, I blame browsers historically for allowing so many mistakes. HTML (pre XHTML) accepts a lot of not-exactly-correct markup, and so does JS, and that's why web development is such a lazy, buggy arena..

Comment: Damn, I shohld have copy-pasted the code instead of manually hacking it in. I edited the question. The typo was not the problem, sorry.

Comment: IE9's rendering mode does not affect the JS engine, so testing code in IE8 mode doesn't tell anything about the actual result in IE8

Comment: @Pumbaa80: That's remarkable, because `JSON.stringify` is not available when emulating IE7, whereas it is with normal IE9.

Comment: @pimvdb `JSON` is not part of the JS engine, it's a "host object".

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Then I'm not sure what's causing your problem. `JSON` is specified in the ECMAScript specification, so it would not be a host object.

Comment: Ah right. I mixed up that one. Does IE9 actually switch engines? That would be pretty interesting. Would you mind comparing the outputs of [ScriptEngineBuildVersion(), ScriptEngineMajorVersion(), ScriptEngineMinorVersion()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tc5a343.aspx#sectionToggle0) in IE9/IE8 mode? Can't do it myself, since I'm running IE8 on XP.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: You are correct. `ScriptEngineMajorVersion` returns `9` on IE7, 8 and 9 emulated on IE9.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact issue today. I had defined a couple of "exception classes" in the parent window, which I "imported" into the child window (iframe) to be able to handle them with `instanceof` in the parent. Something like this:

**Parent window**

```
window.MyExceptions = {
    RenderingException: function () { ... }
    // ...more exception types
};

// Somewhere further down in the code, assuming 'iframe' is the child iframe
try {
    iframe.contentWindow.renderAllTheThings();
} catch (ex) {
    if (ex instanceof MyExceptions.RenderingException) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Child (iframe) window**

```
window.MyExceptions = window.parent.MyExceptions; // Import exception types
window.renderAllTheThings = function () {
    // ...
    throw new MyExceptions.RenderingException();
};
```

Using this setup, I got the same problem as you did - it worked in all modern browsers I tested, but failed in IE8 with the "uncaught exception" error.

My workaround was to add a simple utility function to the MyExceptions object in the parent window that does the actual throwing, like this:

```
window.MyExceptions = {
    RenderingException: function () { ... },
    // ...more exception types
    Throw: function (ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
};
```

Then whenever I wanted to throw an exception from the child window to be handled in the parent, I would do `MyExceptions.Throw(new MyExceptions.RenderingException());`.

Not exactly elegant, but I needed to get it working.

Comment: So I guess you call it like `parent.MyExceptions.Throw(...)`? That's a neat workaround for my `bar` example, but does not really solve the `foo` problem. Well, I guess we could do some [catch-all magic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780505/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-catch-all-javascript-error-handler) like `window.addEventListener('error', parent.MyExceptions.Throw);` but I can't try that ATM - no IE8 at hand