# Is there such a thing as a 'catch all' JavaScript error handler?

Tags: javascript

I'm finding that with asynchronous callbacks I'm needing to write a try/catch for each callback function.  It seems a bit error prone is there a method or technique whereby I can implement a single top level try/catch that catches everything? If not is the technique that I'm using considered good practice or is there a better way to do things?

Comment: It's very rare to use `try..catch` in JavaScript. If you find yourself using it often, you're writing your code incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways of doing this:

1. Set the [window's `onerror` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror)

   - called with three arguments (message, url, lineNumber)
   - returning `true`(!) prevents the default error handling (making this something like a catch-all)
2. Add an `error` event listener to `window`

   - called with an Error event `e` as its sole argument
   - Calling `e.preventDefault()` prevents default error handling

> If not is the technique that I'm using considered good practice or is there a better way to do things?

Due to the dynamic nature of JavaScript, `try/catch` is very slow. There's almost always better ways, for example: check if something exists before calling a method on it.

```
// bad
try {
    document.getElementById('foo').focus();
} catch(e) {
    alert('foo not found');
}

//good
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
if (el) {
    el.focus();
} else {
    alert('foo not found');
}
```

For your specific situation, please show some of your code; maybe in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, don't do it catch-all, that almost always results in problems (because you can't differentiate between exceptions very well).

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't a good idea to depend on a global catch all, but it isn't a bad idea to have one (in the case where an error is thrown where you might not expect).  This way you can handle uncaught errors the way you would like to.

**Using jQuery:**

```
$(window).error(function (msg, url, line) {

     //do something
});
```